# Parse Query not working at first properly iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Im retrieving parse data to my app depending on the user location.

When i start app first sometimes it Prints "No City" but `if i go to another view and comeback then it works properly`.

also sometimes it shows me the result the otherway around
example : Only show results that where city name is "sydney" but it shows result that city name is not "sydney"

here is my code

```
 func loadData(){
        LiveFeedData.removeAllObjects()

        var findLiveFeedData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Spreads")
        findLiveFeedData.whereKey("location", equalTo: city)
        findLiveFeedData.whereKey("country", equalTo: country)

        if city != ""{
        findLiveFeedData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?)->Void in

            if error == nil{
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects{
                    self.LiveFeedData.addObject(object)
                }
            }


                let array:NSArray = self.LiveFeedData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
                self.LiveFeedData = NSMutableArray(array: array)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }else{
                println("Error")

            }
        }

        }else{
        println("No City")
        }
    }

 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        spinner.startAnimating()
        //Location
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


        self.loadData()

    }
```

Comment: @Muhammad but same thing happening in both query right?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is cal your `loadData` method in your delegate method that handles the reception of a new location, that way you can know that when the query gets called, it's only getting run when you know that both the city and the state are populated and not nil.